# Use emmeans with dummy variables

Tags: r, emmeans

I have data which looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                  score = c(0, 0, -3, -5, 0, -4, -4, -4, -1, -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, -2, -2),
                  visit1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                  visit2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                  visit4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                  visit = c(v1, v1, v1, v1, v2, v2, v2, v2, v3, v3, v3, v3, v4, v4, v4, v4),
                  trt = c(A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P))
```

Now, I fitted a mixed model repeated measures using the mmrm package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmrm/index.html) as follows:

```
fit <- mmrm(formula = score ~ visit1 + visit2 + visit4 + visit2:trt + visit4:trt + us(ID | visit), data = dat)
```

I am interested in the LS means for the treatment groups at the last visit (visit4/V4) and the contrast of this. With the following model `fit2 <- mmrm(formula = score ~ visit + visit:trt + us(ID | visit), data = dat)`  I can simply do `emmeans(m1, specs = pairwise ~ treat | visit)`. However, if I try to do this for the case where I use the 0/1 variables for visit (visit1, visit2, and visit4) I get an error: `Error in h_df_1d_list(est = est, var = var, v_num = v_num, v_denom = v_denom) :  Assertion on 'var' failed: Element 1 is not >= 2.22507e-308.`

I have two questions about this all:

1. What does the error message mean?
2. How do I get the LS means and the contrast between the LS means for and between treatment groups at the last measurement (visit4) in case I want to use the model with the dummy variables for visit?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using the `mmrm` package!

Feel free to post questions or problems also on our GitHub issues at https://github.com/openpharma/mmrm/issues. We will see the questions there much faster than here (I just stumbled across this post accidentally).

Regarding your question, I tried to make this into a full reproducible example, see below. (Note that in the model formula you most likely don't want the 0/1 dummy variables but instead the factor `visit` interaction with `trt`)

```r
v1 <- "visit1"
v2 <- "visit2"
v3 <- "visit3"
v4 <- "visit4"

A <- "Active"
P <- "Placebo"

dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                  score = c(0, 0, -3, -5, 0, -4, -4, -4, -1, -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, -2, -2),
                  visit1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
                  visit2 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                  visit4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                  visit = c(v1, v1, v1, v1, v2, v2, v2, v2, v3, v3, v3, v3, v4, v4, v4, v4),
                  trt = c(A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P))

library(mmrm)
fit <- mmrm(formula = score ~ visit:trt + us(ID | visit), data = dat)
```

However, the problem that is detected by the most recent (0.2.2) `mmrm` package version is shown then with the following error message:

```
  time points have to be unique for each subject, detected following duplicates in data:
    visit ID
2  visit1  1
3  visit1  1
4  visit1  1
6  visit2  2
7  visit2  2
8  visit2  2
10 visit3  3
11 visit3  3
12 visit3  3
14 visit4  4
15 visit4  4
16 visit4  4
```

In general, the MMRM only makes sense (and is allowed by the package) when you have unique visits (time points) per individual. The rationale is that if you had duplicate time points (like twice visit 1) it is not clear how the correlation between these should be modelled.

So, bottom line, I think the `mmrm` fit itself is already erroneous here. In addition the `emmeans` comments from Russ can be helpful, thanks a lot!

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

This fails because there is no predictor named `visit` in your model.

`emmeans()` will not work with dummy variables as predictors. The design of `emmeans()` is to use a reference grid for all combinations of predictor values, and it makes no sense to make a prediction for `visit1 = 1` and `visit2 = 1`, for example.

Re-fit your model with factors as predictors. Or with `score` as a multivariate response. I don't know what `mmrm()` requires, but if it doesn't support one of those possibilities, it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty long answer but maybe it will help pin down what are the issues with hard-coded dummy variables.

**emmeans** is designed in a way that you really should code all factors
as class `factor` (or `ordinal`). For those factors that you want
marginal means for, you have no choice about this. However, for those
who insist on manually coding factors using dummy variables, **emmeans**
will work with those, but not in the same way. Here, I’ll work through
an illustrative example to show the difference. The following code
simulates a somewhat unbalanced dataset with factors `treat` (3 levels)
and `dose` (4 levels).

```
set.seed(24.0306)
dat = expand.grid(treat = factor(LETTERS[1:3]), dose = factor(0:3))
dat = rbind(dat[1:3, ], dat)   # more observations for dose 0
dat = dat[-sample(1:15, 2), ]  # "lose" a couple of observations
### frequencies of factor combinations
with(dat, table(treat, dose))

##      dose
## treat 0 1 2 3
##     A 2 0 1 1
##     B 2 1 1 1
##     C 1 1 1 1

teff = c(-4, 7, -3)      # true treat effects
deff = c(-6, -2, 3, 5)   # true dose effects
dat$y = apply(cbind(as.numeric(dat$treat), as.numeric(dat$dose)), 1, function(idx) {
    34 + teff[idx[1]] + deff[idx[2]] + .6 * rnorm(1)
})
```

Now we will fit two models, one with `dose` as a factor and one with
`dose` manually coded with the same dummy variables:

```
dat = transform(dat,
            d0 = 0 + (dose == "0"),
            d1 = 0 + (dose == "1"),
            d2 = 0 + (dose == "2"),
            d3 = 0 + (dose == "3"))
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
mod.fac = lm(y ~ treat + dose, dat)
mod.dum = lm(y ~ treat + d1 + d2 + d3, dat)
```

We used exactly the same coding, so the coefficients are the same:

```
coef(mod.fac)

## (Intercept)      treatB      treatC       dose1       dose2       dose3 
##  24.2031040  11.1261777   0.6237625   3.9153530   8.4476560  10.5616421

coef(mod.dum)

## (Intercept)      treatB      treatC          d1          d2          d3 
##  24.2031040  11.1261777   0.6237625   3.9153530   8.4476560  10.5616421
```

Now compare the EMMs

```
library(emmeans)
(emm.fac = emmeans(mod.fac, "treat"))

##  treat emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  A       29.9 0.215  7     29.4     30.4
##  B       41.1 0.179  7     40.6     41.5
##  C       30.6 0.197  7     30.1     31.0
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: dose 
## Confidence level used: 0.95

(emm.dum = emmeans(mod.dum, "treat"))

##  treat emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  A       35.7 0.316  7     34.9     36.4
##  B       46.8 0.273  7     46.1     47.4
##  C       36.3 0.263  7     35.7     36.9
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: d1, d2, d3 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The EMMs are *not* the same. What gives? Well, I hope you remember that
EMMs are marginal averages of a reference grid, so let’s look at those:

```
ref_grid(mod.fac)

## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     treat = A, B, C
##     dose = 0, 1, 2, 3

ref_grid(mod.dum)

## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     treat = A, B, C
##     d1 = 0, 1
##     d2 = 0, 1
##     d3 = 0, 1
```

Hmmmm. So each one of the dummy variables is by default regarded as a factor
having two levels. This means that your manual dummy coding makes this
look like a *four*-factor experiment instead of a two-factor one. That
makes a difference!

Another way to see what’s happening is to obtain the linear functions
actually being computed. This information is in the `linfct` slot of the
object created by `emmeans()`. This slot comprises a matrix, and each
row of the matrix contains the weights that are applied to each
regression coefficient. Recall that the regression coefficients
themselves are the same for the two models, so if we were to get the
same linear functions, we’ll get the same EMMs. Here they are:

```
emm.fac@linfct

##      (Intercept) treatB treatC dose1 dose2 dose3
## [1,]           1      0      0  0.25  0.25  0.25
## [2,]           1      1      0  0.25  0.25  0.25
## [3,]           1      0      1  0.25  0.25  0.25

emm.dum@linfct

##      (Intercept) treatB treatC  d1  d2  d3
## [1,]           1      0      0 0.5 0.5 0.5
## [2,]           1      1      0 0.5 0.5 0.5
## [3,]           1      0      1 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Interesting. So each `dose` coefficient gets twice the weight for
`mod.dum` as for `mod.dum`, while both give the same weight to the
intercept and `treat` coefficients. The dummy coding is going to produce wrong answers.

There’s a third interesting possibility. As we saw, **emmeans** by
default views any covariate having just two different values as a
factor. This is a convenience because often we want indicators to be
viewed as factors. But we can force them to be treated as covariates
instead:

```
ref_grid(mod.dum, cov.keep = "")

## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     treat = A, B, C
##     d1 = 0.15385
##     d2 = 0.23077
##     d3 = 0.23077
```

With this setup, the EMMs are not really averages anymore; they are
predictions for the three treatments with the covariates `d1`, `d2`, and
`d3` set to the above values, leading to a third set of EMMs

```
(emm.dum2 = emmeans(mod.dum, "treat", cov.keep = ""))

##  treat emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  A       29.2 0.203  7     28.7     29.7
##  B       40.3 0.177  7     39.9     40.7
##  C       29.8 0.200  7     29.3     30.3
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95

emm.dum2@linfct

##      (Intercept) treatB treatC        d1        d2        d3
## [1,]           1      0      0 0.1538462 0.2307692 0.2307692
## [2,]           1      1      0 0.1538462 0.2307692 0.2307692
## [3,]           1      0      1 0.1538462 0.2307692 0.2307692
```

Now since the dummies are just 0s and 1s, the values of these in the
reference grid are just the fractions of each that are equal to 1. So
this suggests how we can get the above results from `mod.fac`:

```
emmeans(mod.fac, "treat", weights = "prop")

##  treat emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  A       29.2 0.203  7     28.7     29.7
##  B       40.3 0.177  7     39.9     40.7
##  C       29.8 0.200  7     29.3     30.3
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: dose 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

That is, manually coded dummies, when treated as covariates, yield
*proportionally-weighted* EMMs instead of the default equally-weighted
ones. We can turn this around by modifying what covariate values to use with the dummy coding so that we get the equally-weighted EMMs:

```
emmeans(mod.dum, "treat", cov.keep = "", cov.reduce = function(x) 0.25)

##  treat emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  A       29.9 0.215  7     29.4     30.4
##  B       41.1 0.179  7     40.6     41.5
##  C       30.6 0.197  7     30.1     31.0
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Aha! We have come full circle, as this is the first set of EMMs we obtained from `mod.fac`.

#### Summary

All this shows that:

- You may not use manual dummy coding for the factor for which you
  want estimated marginal means
- For factors to be marginalized out, dummy coding can create false
  factors that yield *incorrect* EMMs
- If you use `cov.keep = ""` with dummy coding, you will obtain
  proportionately-weighted EMMs, provided that your manual coding
  corresponds to `contr.treatment` coding.

All in all, life is really much simpler, in my opinion, if you avoid
using manualy-created dummies.

##### Left as an exercise:

What happens if you use `contr.sum` dummies: `e1 = d1 - d0`,
`e2 = d2 - d0`, `e3 = d3 - d0`? *Hint*: In a way, this is simpler
because you don’t need to specify `cov.keep`, as these dummies have
three different values and will be treated as covariates from the
get-go.